# how to retry sidekiq job without raising exceptions?

Tags: ruby, sidekiq

Simple stuff, i need to have a way to retry a job WITHOUT RAISING THE EXCEPTION.
I know I can use something like

```
def perform
    if stuff_happening
        perform_in(2.min)
        return
    end
end
```

and its fine, but there is one problem: retry count. potentially, with stuff_happening every time, this job will keep scheduling indefinitely? is there a way to ensure it will only be scheduled a fix number of times and then stop?

Comment: I think sidekiq retry automatically https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Error-Handling#automatic-job-retry

Comment: Could you share more about the "without raising exceptions"? Sidekiq's retry mechanism is tied to exceptions. So working around your exceptions thing would probably be much better.

Answer (score 0):

*Sidenote:* we use 2 spaces for indent in Ruby.

You need to pass the state (amount of retries already happened) through:

```
def perform(attempts_left = 10)
  if stuff_happening && attempts_left > 0
    perform_in(2.min, attempts_left - 1)
    return
  end
end
```